# UnixException on Mac

Tags: java, macos, mac

Начал получить ошибку на *Mac* при попытке записать `pdf` файл в папку `temp`. Вернее, приложение должно записывать туда файл, но не записывает (исключения не падают). А затем необходимо получить доступ к файлу, но его в папке нет. Соответственно падает исключение (см. ниже).
Видел топики с похожими проблемами. У коллеги на `win` такой ошибки нет. Соответственно делаю вывод, что проблема в *ОС*.
Разрешения на папку стоят. Буквально вчера такой проблемы не было.
Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо разбираться с тем почему Ваше приложение не записывает файл. Неплохо бы увидеть код, который пишет в файл.

Comment: в маке нет папки `/temp`, есть только `/tmp`. покажите права на эту папку `ls -al /path/to/your/temp`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Папка создается в папке приложения.)

Comment: @АртёмБондарев приложите кусок кода, как вы создаете и сохраняете

Comment: @SeniorPomidor код приложить не могу. Но он совершенно не изменился.

Comment: сложно говорить в чем у вас проблема, если не вижу кода.  может быть, изначально папки нет, а вы пишете туда, и когда обращаетесь, то говорит нет папки. попробуйте это проверить.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor пробовал задавать папку самостоятельно. Финальный архив в нее пишется. А шаблоны pdf файлов - нет.
Удалял эту папку вручную, когда столкнулся с проблемой. Как уже понял, проблема была не в этом.
Опять же, хочу напомнить, что на других устройствах такой проблемы нет.